# How do I access properties from within an Ember 2 component?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I am having some trouble accessing properties passed to my Ember component, which is as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    isRowEditorActive: function() {
        return this.get('items').length > 0;
    }.property('items'),

    actions: {
        // My actions here
    }
});
```

The `items` (list of strings) that I pass in, can be accessed without problems within the template `{{line-items-table items=['asd', 'asd']}}`

However trying to `get` them within the component just returns undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should put it in a wrapper object in controller>  lineItemParams: { items: ['foo', 'bar'] }     {{line-items-table params=lineItemParams}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@kristjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061233/kristjan-reinhold) says, you'll need to define your `items` for the `line-item-table` in the parent.

This is due to that the current version of handlebars don't support inline arrays, https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1058